# replacement for "functionality" buzzword?

Tags: documentation, communication, buzzword-compliance

Of all the annoying buzzwords, "functionality" is the worst when I am in the middle of writing a specification (as I am now): "these requirements define the functionality to be included in version 2"..."as part of the download functionality, we need to capture blah blah blah" (Don't get me started on "capture")

"Functionality" is too cumbersome, and makes it sound like you are trying to make something sound more important than it is. "Capability" works sometimes, and sometimes "function" itself works; "subsystem" might work at times too...but we need a simple word for the concept of "set of related functions", preferably in 3 syllables or less. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about English usage. [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Features.

How about that? Simple, to the point, not spin.

Comment: That is perfect...how did I forget that word?

Comment: Buzzword induced hypnosis, I presume.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> > The user manager page is where all of the user management <strike>functionality</strike> **love nuggets** reside.

or what about:

> > The portal features a budgeting subsystem, wherein all of the budgeting <strike>functionality</strike> **goodie gum drops** can be derived.

or even:

> > By clicking on the submit button, you'll be showered with all of the wonderful <strike>functionality</strike> **hot mommies** that one could hope for.

These have all worked well for me when specifying the functionality that will be in my new projects. YMMV...

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, this is a tricky one. For smaller items I often use the very buzz-wordy "widget", which works pretty well for self-encapsulated systems.

"Functions" as a plural also works in some contexts - as can "actions" (as in 'the application needs to be able to perform the following actions...').